# In a <select multiple> tag, how to put the values from selected <option> tags to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu, multiple-select

I have this code:

```html
<select multiple id="test">
  <option value="A">Option A</option>
  <option value="B">Option B</option>
  <option value="C">Option C</option>
  <option value="D">Option D</option>
</select>
```

If the user selects A and C, is there a way to put those values in an array? If the select is not multiple, I can use `option = document.getElementById('test').value;`. But if it's multiple then I don't know how to do it. Because we can only use one `value` attribute, not an array of attributes. The documentations for [<option>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) and [<select>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) aren't useful. There is also [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54296581/3416774) but I'm not sure how to apply it.

What I want is to put them into a string:

```js
string = 'You select` + optionarray[0] + ' and ' + optionarray[1] + ' and ' + optionarray[2] + ... //until there is no more element left
```

Comment: loop through all the options and check if each is selected.

Comment: You can use the ["selectedOptions"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) property of the select tag. It contains a list of selected options within the select element. There is an example on the page I am linking to.